# How to spread a variable in AutoHotkey?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, autohotkey, spread-syntax

In JavaScript, we use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to spread an array of items, e.g.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]

console.log(...arr) // 1 2 3
```

And I want to achieve a similar effect in AHK:

```
Position := [A_ScreenWidth / 2, A_ScreenHeight]

MouseMove Position ;  how to spread it?
```

Comment: There is no spread syntax in AHK that I know of. You'd have to access the array elements "by hand".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no spread syntax in AHK, but there are some alternatives:

For big arrays you can use:

```
position := [A_ScreenWidth / 2, A_ScreenHeight]
Loop,% position.Count()
    MsgBox % position[A_Index] ; show a message box with the content of any value
```

or

```
position := [A_ScreenWidth / 2, A_ScreenHeight]
For index, value in position
    MsgBox % value ; show a message box with the content of any value
```

In your example, can be:

```
position := [A_ScreenWidth / 2, A_ScreenHeight]
MouseMove, position[1], position[2]
```

This will move your mouse to the bottom middle of your screen.

To avoid decimals, you may use `Floor()`, `Round()`, `Ceil()` functions for example, like:

```
position := [ Floor( A_ScreenWidth / 2 ), Round( A_ScreenHeight ) ]
Loop,% position.Count()
    MsgBox % position[A_Index] ; show a message box with the content of any value
```